# AngularJS: ng-model-options bind form value on Submit doesn't work with multiple selections

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angular-ngmodel

I have a form with three radio buttons, and deferred binding to model on click of submit. Live example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9oAzEQcUS9g7g91zo5Oy?p=preview)

This works perfectly fine in the happy path scenario:

1. Select `radio1` > click `submit` gives `radio1` as the result.

But in the following scenario it breaks:

1. Select radio1 > click submit > gives `radio1`
2. Now select `radio2` > then `radio3` > and then click `submit`.
3. This gives `radio2` instead of `radio3` as the bound value.

Basically, if I make multiple changes to the radio group, only the *first* change gets captured. How can I change this behaviour to reflect the *last* change instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use allowInvalid : true in ngModelOptions to validate correctly instead of the default behavior of setting the model to undefined. See [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions).

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1" ng-model="radioValue" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit', allowInvalid : true}" >
      <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio2" ng-model="radioValue" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit', allowInvalid : true}">
      <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio3" ng-model="radioValue" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit', allowInvalid : true}">
```

Working Plunker [Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/jkd6xKqOhHkF8XtckHRO?p=preview)

Comment: Brilliant. That worked like a charm. I should've read up better. Thanks a ton!!